# Application path lost when bringing a webapp into maven

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, maven, tomcat

Good Morning,

I have an issue with maven webapp archetype. I have a Spring web application which works fine without maven. The problem is that I must bring it into Maven.

First step : I create a Maven webapp archetype project.
Second step : I bring my libraries into pom.xml
Third step : I bring my classes on src/main/java, my jsps on webapp/WEB-INF/view

At this stage, When I run the project, it still works fine. However if I need to clean and build the project for a reason (addition to pom.xml), the Tomcat Server (tomcat  9) won't load the app and returns a 404 error.

When I look at the log, I got no error, just cannot find the web application

Here is my pom.xml :

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0   http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>fr.alteca</groupId>
<artifactId>outilIndicateursV13</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>outilIndicateursV13 Maven Webapp</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
<properties>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <maven.compile.source>1.8</maven.compile.source>
    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
    <springframework.version>4.3.9.RELEASE</springframework.version>
    <springsecurity.version>4.2.3.RELEASE</springsecurity.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>

    <!-- spring-orm -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- spring tx -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>${springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- spring AOP -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.13</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- spring MVC -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- spring Security -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>${springsecurity.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>${springsecurity.version}</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- mysql-connector-java -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.44</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- postgresql -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>42.1.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- hibernate-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.12.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- jackson-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- jackson annotations -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- validation-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- junit -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- javax-servlet-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>



</dependencies>
<build>
    <finalName>outil-indicateursV11</finalName>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.0</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

Here is the server log :

```
    déc. 01, 2017 9:33:37 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule     begin
    AVERTISSEMENT: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context}     Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.server:outilIndicateursV13' did not find a matching property.
déc. 01, 2017 9:33:37 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFOS: Server version:        Apache Tomcat/9.0.1
    déc. 01, 2017 9:33:37 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener     log
    INFOS: Server built:          Sep 27 2017 17:31:52 UTC
    déc. 01, 2017 9:33:37 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFOS: Server number:         9.0.1.0
    déc. 01, 2017 9:33:37 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFOS: OS Name:               Windows 7
    déc. 01, 2017 9:33:37 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener   log
    INFOS: OS Version:            6.1
    déc. 01, 2017 9:33:37 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener     log
    INFOS: Architecture:          amd64
    déc. 01, 2017 9:33:37 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFOS: Java Home:             C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre
    déc. 01, 2017 9:33:37 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFOS: JVM Version:           1.8.0_144-b01
    déc. 01, 2017 9:33:37 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFOS: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
déc. 01, 2017 9:33:37 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFOS: CATALINA_BASE:         D:\DEV\OUTIL_INDICATEURS\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp3
déc. 01, 2017 9:33:37 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFOS: CATALINA_HOME:         C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0
déc. 01, 2017 9:33:37 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFOS: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=D:\DEV\OUTIL_INDICATEURS\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp3
déc. 01, 2017 9:33:37 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFOS: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0
déc. 01, 2017 9:33:37 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFOS: Command line argument: -Dwtp.deploy=D:\DEV\OUTIL_INDICATEURS\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp3\wtpwebapps
déc. 01, 2017 9:33:37 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFOS: Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\endorsed
déc. 01, 2017 9:33:37 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFOS: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252
déc. 01, 2017 9:33:37 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFOS: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: [C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_144/bin/server;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_144/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_144/lib/amd64;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\Windows\CCM;C:\Windows\CCM;C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd;C:\Windows\system32;;.]
déc. 01, 2017 9:33:38 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFOS: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
déc. 01, 2017 9:33:38 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFOS: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
déc. 01, 2017 9:33:38 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFOS: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
déc. 01, 2017 9:33:38 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFOS: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
déc. 01, 2017 9:33:38 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFOS: Initialization processed in 873 ms
déc. 01, 2017 9:33:38 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFOS: Démarrage du service [Catalina]
déc. 01, 2017 9:33:38 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFOS: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/9.0.1
déc. 01, 2017 9:33:40 AM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFOS: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
déc. 01, 2017 9:33:42 AM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFOS: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
déc. 01, 2017 9:33:42 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFOS: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
déc. 01, 2017 9:33:42 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFOS: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
déc. 01, 2017 9:33:42 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFOS: Server startup in 4309 ms
```

Spring Config is a no-xml based and looks like this :

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass = true)
@ComponentScan(basePackages="fr.alteca.outilIndicateurs")
public class AppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/app/**").addResourceLocations("/app/");
    }

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();

        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/view/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");

        return viewResolver;
    }

}
```

and the initializer class :

```
public class WebAppInit implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    private static final String DISPATCHER_SERVLET_NAME = "dispatcher";

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext container) throws ServletException {

         // Create the 'root' Spring application context
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext rootContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        rootContext.register(AppConfig.class, DBConfig.class, SecurityConfig.class);

        // Manage the lifecycle of the root application context
        container.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(rootContext));

        // Create the dispatcher servlet's Spring application context
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext dispatcherServlet = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        dispatcherServlet.register(AppConfig.class);

        // Register and map the dispatcher servlet
        ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = container.addServlet(DISPATCHER_SERVLET_NAME, new DispatcherServlet(dispatcherServlet));
        dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        dispatcher.addMapping("/");

    }
```

The root mapping at the controller's side :

```
@Controller
public class LoginController {


    @Autowired
    CustomAuthentificationProvider provider;

    @InitBinder // preprocesses the data comming into our controller.
    public void initBinder(WebDataBinder databinder) {
        StringTrimmerEditor stringTrimmerEditor = new StringTrimmerEditor(true); // trims the leading and the trailing whitespace - if parameter true, will trim to null if there is only whitespace
        databinder.registerCustomEditor(String.class, stringTrimmerEditor); // for each String object apply the string trimmer.
    }

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String showLogin(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("utilisateur", new Utilisateur());
        return "login-page";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/processLogin")
    public String processLogin(
            @Valid @ModelAttribute("utilisateur") Utilisateur utilisateur, BindingResult result)
    { 


        System.out.println("UserName : "+ utilisateur.getUtilisateur_login());
        System.out.println("UserPassword : "+ utilisateur.getUtilisateur_password());

        utilisateur = provider.identifier(utilisateur.getUtilisateur_login(), utilisateur.getUtilisateur_password());

        System.out.println("Utilisateur retourné par le provider d'authentification = "+utilisateur);

        if(result.hasErrors() | utilisateur==null) return "login-page"; else return "index";

    }

}
```

I checked maven parameters in eclipse, tomcat 9 parameters, for 48 without finding a solution. And I don't want to create a new project each time I need to add a library in my POM.xml. Can someone put me on the right path so I can have a better understanding of this issue. Don't hesitate to ask questions, i'll provide required information.

Server log

```
    2017-12-01 10:13:19 Commons Daemon procrun stderr initialized
01-Dec-2017 10:13:21.323 INFOS [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version:        Apache Tomcat/9.0.1
01-Dec-2017 10:13:21.332 INFOS [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:          Sep 27 2017 17:31:52 UTC
01-Dec-2017 10:13:21.333 INFOS [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server number:         9.0.1.0
01-Dec-2017 10:13:21.333 INFOS [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:               Windows 7
01-Dec-2017 10:13:21.334 INFOS [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Version:            6.1
01-Dec-2017 10:13:21.334 INFOS [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture:          amd64
01-Dec-2017 10:13:21.334 INFOS [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:             C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_144
01-Dec-2017 10:13:21.338 INFOS [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Version:           1.8.0_144-b01
01-Dec-2017 10:13:21.338 INFOS [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
01-Dec-2017 10:13:21.339 INFOS [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:         C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0
01-Dec-2017 10:13:21.339 INFOS [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:         C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0
01-Dec-2017 10:13:21.339 INFOS [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0
01-Dec-2017 10:13:21.340 INFOS [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0
01-Dec-2017 10:13:21.340 INFOS [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\temp
01-Dec-2017 10:13:21.340 INFOS [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
01-Dec-2017 10:13:21.341 INFOS [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\conf\logging.properties
01-Dec-2017 10:13:21.341 INFOS [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: exit
01-Dec-2017 10:13:21.341 INFOS [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Xms128m
01-Dec-2017 10:13:21.342 INFOS [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Xmx256m
01-Dec-2017 10:13:21.342 INFOS [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\Windows\CCM;C:\Windows\CCM;C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd;;.]
01-Dec-2017 10:13:21.697 INFOS [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
01-Dec-2017 10:13:21.798 GRAVE [main] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException Failed to initialize component [Connector[HTTP/1.1-8080]]
 org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: L''initialisation du gestionnaire de protocole a échoué
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:935)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:136)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:530)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:136)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:852)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:136)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:622)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:645)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:311)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:494)
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.initServerSocket(NioEndpoint.java:227)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:202)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.init(AbstractEndpoint.java:1039)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init(AbstractProtocol.java:540)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Protocol.init(AbstractHttp11Protocol.java:70)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:932)
    ... 13 more


    01-Dec-2017 10:13:21.799 INFOS [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
01-Dec-2017 10:13:21.801 GRAVE [main] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException Failed to initialize component [Connector[AJP/1.3-8009]]
 org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: L''initialisation du gestionnaire de protocole a échoué
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:935)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:136)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:530)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:136)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:852)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:136)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:622)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:645)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:311)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:494)
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.initServerSocket(NioEndpoint.java:227)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:202)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.init(AbstractEndpoint.java:1039)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init(AbstractProtocol.java:540)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:932)
    ... 13 more

01-Dec-2017 10:13:21.802 INFOS [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Initialization processed in 1077 ms
01-Dec-2017 10:13:21.898 INFOS [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Démarrage du service [Catalina]
01-Dec-2017 10:13:21.898 INFOS [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/9.0.1
01-Dec-2017 10:13:21.924 INFOS [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Déploiement de l'archive [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\webapps\outilIndicateursV13.war] de l'application web
01-Dec-2017 10:13:22.814 INFOS [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web application archive [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\webapps\outilIndicateursV13.war] has finished in [889] ms
01-Dec-2017 10:13:22.815 INFOS [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Déploiement du répertoire [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\webapps\docs] de l'application web
01-Dec-2017 10:13:22.855 INFOS [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\webapps\docs] has finished in [41] ms
01-Dec-2017 10:13:22.855 INFOS [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Déploiement du répertoire [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\webapps\examples] de l'application web
01-Dec-2017 10:13:24.530 INFOS [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\webapps\examples] has finished in [1 675] ms
01-Dec-2017 10:13:24.531 INFOS [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Déploiement du répertoire [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\webapps\host-manager] de l'application web
01-Dec-2017 10:13:24.672 INFOS [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\webapps\host-manager] has finished in [141] ms
01-Dec-2017 10:13:24.673 INFOS [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Déploiement du répertoire [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\webapps\manager] de l'application web
01-Dec-2017 10:13:24.705 INFOS [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\webapps\manager] has finished in [32] ms
01-Dec-2017 10:13:24.705 INFOS [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Déploiement du répertoire [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\webapps\ROOT] de l'application web
01-Dec-2017 10:13:24.800 INFOS [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\webapps\ROOT] has finished in [95] ms
01-Dec-2017 10:13:24.802 INFOS [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 2999 ms
01-Dec-2017 10:13:24.806 GRAVE [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.await StandardServer.await: create[localhost:8005]: 
 java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.bind0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.bind(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.await(StandardServer.java:422)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.await(Catalina.java:759)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:705)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:355)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:495)
```

Comment: Are you running the tomcat within the eclipse?

have you added your application to tomcat server?

Comment: yes I published it to tomcat, it appears in the list under eclipse's server tab

Comment: Tomcat v9.0 Server at localhost [started, Synchronized]
outilInidcateursV13 [synchronized]

Comment: some how you internal tomcat is not picking up the application [If this was not the case, your application/war name must be present in server startup logs]. You can test this scenario by exporting the war, moving the war to webapps and running the tomcat outside eclipse.

Comment: I can only run tomcat inside eclipse as tomcat disconnects showing an error message saying that with no service or application using it tomcat closes automatically.

Comment: Sorry I did not see it. Inside webapps there is a folder outilIndicateursv13 with meta inf and web inf

Comment: After the external tomcat window is closed automatically, please go to logs directory (present at the same level of webapps) and refer catalina.out for descriptive error. Because tomcat server runs without problem even if no application is deployed in it.

Comment: Sorry I did not see it. Inside webapps there is a folder outilIndicateursv13 with meta inf and web inf. Is that what we are looking after?

Comment: no descriptive logs will be present in log directory inside CATALINA_HOME directory. It the one where bin, webapps, conf etc are present. You will not find logs directory inside webapps but one level above. If logs directory not available, you need to set CATALINA_HOME environment variable to enable proper tomcat logging.

Comment: I got a log named tomcat9-stderr.2017-12-012. Give me a minute

Comment: updated my question with server log